# AngularJS / Web API Javascript files versioning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, msbuild, versioning, msbuild-task

What is the best practice for versioning javascript files (add version number as query string for each js file in my index.html page)

Please note I am using ASP.NET Web APIs and angularjs.

Is it possible to do that through msbuild as am using it? what is the task or command for that?

I tried this in javascript but it's not working

```
<script src="app/controllers/app.js?{{version}}"></script>
```

And this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="app/controllers/app.js' + {{version}} +'"></script>');
</script>
```

I can't use ASP.Net bundling or grunt, I need different solutions.

Comment: you describe a CMS, but it sounds like you need to roll your own or do a simple replace() on the content before you ship it to the client..

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, {{version}} should be work if you have a scope reference to it in the index controller of the page.

Else, you could simply try something like this:

```
<script src="app/controllers/app.js?v=2"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience using {{version}} might not work, As angular controllers and scope will not be in action before all your  tags get loaded. As suggested by Dev-One, you can hardcode a number with your files.

Don't forget to change (increment) this number each time you deploy a new assembly.

Comment: That's why I want to use {{version}} So I don't need to change it every release (specially that I have many JS files)

Comment: I know its kind of tedious, but seems its the only way out (I am really looking forward to any other solutions). In case you have lot many js , you can replace them all together by replace all.

Ex: replace ?v100 by ?v101